# How to put CAPTCHA on wordpress website before anyone can use any page on it

Tags: php, html, wordpress, security, captcha

We tried a lot using plugin , html code in header footer but it didn't work

What we are trying to do

- it should work on wordpress
- trying to put code in header footer script
- every visitor have to enter CAPTCHA once in 6 hours
- it's okay if it's completely hide our website on Search engine

Give us some ideas
Please

Answer (score 0):

```
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
  // How this code snippet works:
  // This logic overwrites the default behavior of `grecaptcha.ready()` to
  // ensure that it can be safely called at any time. When `grecaptcha.ready()`
  // is called before reCAPTCHA is loaded, the callback function that is passed
  // by `grecaptcha.ready()` is enqueued for execution after reCAPTCHA is
  // loaded.
  if(typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
    grecaptcha = {};
  }
  grecaptcha.ready = function(cb){
    if(typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
      // window.__grecaptcha_cfg is a global variable that stores reCAPTCHA's
      // configuration. By default, any functions listed in its 'fns' property
      // are automatically executed when reCAPTCHA loads.
      const c = '___grecaptcha_cfg';
      window[c] = window[c] || {};
      (window[c]['fns'] = window[c]['fns']||[]).push(cb);
    } else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // Usage
  grecaptcha.ready(function(){
    grecaptcha.render("container", {
      sitekey: "ABC-123"
    });
  });
</script>
```